# How do I log out of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

I want to logout of Stack Overflow, and I want to use a different account. There is no logout button/link. How do I sign out? (I'm not signed in to Google right now either.)

Why is there not a logout button on the top of the page like every other website ever?

Comment: *There is no logout button/link* Yes there is. That's how you log out.

Answer (score 5):

Click on "Stack Exchange" in the upper left hand corner of the page and click "log out".

Answer (score 2):

1. Click StackExchange in the top left.
2. Click log out.

Comment: If I want to log in (after logout) I'm immediately logged in without providing any credentials. Is this how logout should work?